# Error al actualizar paquetes React.js

Tags: javascript

Bien, el día de hoy actualicé un proyecto React que tenia como dos meses sin moverse, al momento de hacerlo me genera un error al momento de iniciar la app diciendo:

Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
   See https://fb.me/react-invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

El código esta bien y funcionaba bien ya que está en línea dicho proyecto, pero el momento de actualizar y querer iniciarlo en modo local para hacer modificaciones me apareció ese error. Lo siguiente son las dependencias y su versión. ¿Alguien tiene idea de que ocurrió?

```
"dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.4",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.58",
    "@sweetalert2/themes": "^5.0.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.1.9",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.6.1",
    "react-data-table-component": "^6.11.7",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-paypal-button-v2": "^2.6.3",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.4",
    "react-router-bootstrap": "^0.25.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.3",
    "redux": "^4.1.0",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "styled-component": "^2.8.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.0",
    "sweetalert": "^2.1.2",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.0"
},
```

Comment: El mensaje se refiere a una función hook que se esta llamando de forma inválida, ¿Te dice la ruta del archivo donde esta el error? Saludos

Comment: No dice ruta ni línea del código (no dice específicamente, me esta generalizando y me marca node_modules e index.js). Todo funciona si no actualizo las dependencias. El único error que sale es el del post. Algo raro que note, en que en mis componentes yo antes tenia mis return con <> </> para devolver, pero ahora que actualice salio que era invalido y los coloque con Fragments; unas vez que lo hice inicié y me salio ese error